# Unity+Photon: Smooth follow remote controlled RigidBody

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, smoothing, photon, rigid-bodies

I have a racing game functionality that when the local player died, he can watch a remote player in chase view until the race ends.
The camera script is set up in a way that there is no jitter when following a locally controlled RigidBody. It gets very jittery however when following a remote controlled RigidBody since I don't know how I could compensate the lag.

Is there any way to smooth out the camera in this case? Here is my current follow functionality in the camera script:

```
private void Start()
{
    positionDamping = 10f;
    rotationDamping = 10f;
    StartCoroutine(LateFixedUpdate());
}

IEnumerator LateFixedUpdate()
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        Follow();
    }
}

void Follow()
{
    wantedRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerFrontView.position - transform.position);     
    wantedPosition = target.TransformPoint(0, height, -distance);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, wantedRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationDamping);
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, wantedPosition, Time.deltaTime * positionDamping);
}
```

EDIT: The camera GameObject is not childed under the RigidBody.

Comment: Maybe try to use translate and lookat and resign from Slerp and lerp
`void Follow()
{
    Vector3 translation = player.position - transform.position;
    translation.x = 0.0f;
    transform.Translate(translation, Space.World);
    transform.LookAt(player);
}`

Comment: I also recommend you to read about movement interpolation / prediction in multiplayer games. It is known and popular technique and it can help in cases similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Your code made my camera act like it was childed to the game object. However, I need some sort of "soft" transition - like the camera is mounted to the car with a rubber band instead of a steel beam. But your code gave me an idea to soften out the effect a bit more when following remote players. This, and your advice to look up about prediction coding should help me alot. Thank you :)